# Regression and ANOVA of factors

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

I am doing research on automated banking service quality.  In my work I have found in total 6 dimensions (factors): 4 service quality (SQ) factors, 1 customer satisfaction (CS) factor and 1 loyalty factor. All factors have multiple items. Now, I want to apply regression analysis using SPSS and make an equation of the form:

CS=a+b1(SQ factor1)+b2(SQ factor2)+....

Note: Independent as well as dependent both are factors and not items. How can I apply regression on all factors? I used Command in factor analysis “save variables as factor score”. As dependent variable is also a factor score and not a single item, so applying linear regression in SPSS is not giving proper results. If dependent variable would have been a single item then it would have shown proper results.

1. Which method shall I apply to compute scores representing factors for using them in regression and ANOVA.
2. Which regression method will be most appropriate one ...linear, PLS etc and how to apply the same on factors?
3. Can I use mean value as a representative value of factors for regression (any citation for that)?

Comment: Please do not post the same question repeatedly. It may take a while to get an answer.